# Why does entity framework uses “set transaction isolation level read committed” and what does this mean?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework, and I have tracked SQL Server using SQL Server Profiler. And I found that when I query the database using EF, the SQL Profiler will show the following:

```
set transaction isolation level read committed.
```

So what does this mean?

Comment: Is not EF specific. Google the string and find out all about it.

Answer (score 3):

You should check the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) about isolation levels. I guess you know transactions a little bit, the `SaveContext()` saves the changes in a transaction. There are several transaction levels, with increasing error filtering capabilities and decreasing performance. It is a good task to find the balance between safety and performance.

The `read committed` transaction level protects you from "dirty reads", but doesn't protect from "non-repeatable reads" and "phantom reads" (see wiki). Kinda deep topic, but you shall go through it once you plan to create more complicated and safe systems.

You can modify the transaction level like it is written [here](http://www.programminginterviews.info/2012/06/entity-framework-transaction-scope.html). But for basic applications you won't need this.